# How to validate input consistency (or relation between fields/combination of fields) in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, input

Assuming we have an array of input fields named (a, b, c, d) and we need to validate some relationship between them.

For simplicity, let's assume all of them are numbers and we need to validate that the sum `a + b` is greater than `c + d`.

Other example can be validating multiple non-overlapping date ranges.

How can we define the validation rules and which fields should receive the error?

Is there already a design pattern for this kind of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 


// Laravel now has a function called `prepareForValidation` in request class
// applicable for Laravel version 5.6+. You can use that to validate :


namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class YourCustomRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'a' => 'required|numeric',
            'b' => 'required|numeric',
            'c' => 'required|numeric',
            'd' => 'required|numeric',
            // Validate if sum_a_b value is greater than sum_c_d value
            'sum_a_b' => 'gt:sum_c_d'
        ];
    }


    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        // Add new fields with values representing the sums
        $request->merge([
            'sum_a_b' => $this->input('a') + $this->input('b'),
    }
}


// And then in your controller's post action

public function store(YourCustomRequest $request)
{
    // Do actions when vaidation is successful
}
```